# Springfox Swagger generation creates odd schema

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using Springfox-swagger to generate a Swagger page for my Spring Boot REST service. As a part of one of my POJOs that I serialise to JSON I use:

- `javax.money.MonetaryAmount`
- `java.time.LocalDate`

The issue I'm seeing is that in Swagger, the Model and Model Shema tabs for the response show the implementation details of these fields, namely

```
LocalDate {
 chronology (IsoChronology, optional),
 dayOfMonth (integer, optional),
 dayOfWeek (string, optional) = ['MONDAY' or 'TUESDAY' or 'WEDNESDAY' or 'THURSDAY' or 'FRIDAY' or 'SATURDAY' or 'SUNDAY'],
 dayOfYear (integer, optional),
 era (Era, optional),
 leapYear (boolean, optional),
 month (string, optional) = ['JANUARY' or 'FEBRUARY' or 'MARCH' or 'APRIL' or 'MAY' or 'JUNE' or 'JULY' or 'AUGUST' or 'SEPTEMBER' or 'OCTOBER' or 'NOVEMBER' or 'DECEMBER'],
 monthValue (integer, optional),
 year (integer, optional)
}
IsoChronology {
  calendarType (string, optional),
  id (string, optional)
}
Era {
  value (integer, optional)
}
```

and

```
MonetaryAmount {
  context (MonetaryContext, optional),
  currency (CurrencyUnit, optional),
  factory (MonetaryAmountFactory«MonetaryAmount», optional),
  negative (boolean, optional),
  negativeOrZero (boolean, optional),
  number (NumberValue, optional),
  positive (boolean, optional),
  positiveOrZero (boolean, optional),
  zero (boolean, optional)
}
MonetaryContext {
  (...)
}
CurrencyUnit {
  (...)
}
CurrencyContext {
  (...)
}
MonetaryAmountFactory«MonetaryAmount» {
  (...)
}
NumberValue {
  (...)
}
```

I am using the Moneta 1.1 implementation of `javax.money.MonetaryAmount` (JSR 354) if that matters.

Now, this is far to verbose for what I want, so I implemented a Serialiser, and my response (and requests) work as expected. However, the *schemas* are not reflecting this. Is there a way of configuring the format of the schemas after serialising the requests?

As I realise there are quite a few moving parts to this problem, I've created a [proof of concept project](https://github.com/kinbiko/swagger-poc) to show the problem in its full glory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [your example](https://github.com/kinbiko/swagger-poc/blob/master/src/main/java/poc/serializers/PocPojoSerializer.java#L22-L23) looks like you're converting `MonetaryAmount` to `double` and `LocalDate` to `String` in your serializers.

Because springfox cannot introspect the jackson machinery (at least not yet :-)), we need to tell SpringFox what you're doing in your serializers. To do that, as described in [the documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger2-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot) in your docket you can provide a hint by providing alternate type rules.

```java
docket
      .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
      .directModelSubstitute(MonetaryAmount.class, Double.class)
```

There are three ways to do this, either via `directModelSubstitutes` for regular types, `genericModelSubstitutes` for single type argument generic types and `alternateTypeRules` for more complex generic type use cases.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way of doing more localised substitution? I.e. LocalDate -> String one place and LocalDate -> Long in another?

Comment: Found the answer: You can use `@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "com.qualified.ReplacedWith")` on the getters of the POJO.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. That's what I'd have suggested 